# WhereIn condition with UUID not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, uuid

My `whereIn()` condition using a UUID is not working for me in Laravel.

```
public function skills($id)
{
    $skills = DB::table("industry_skill_sets")
        ->whereIn('industry_id', [$id])
        ->pluck("name", "id");
    
    print_r($skills);
    
    exit;
}
```

Here my id is the UUID separated by commas. So when I echo id, I am getting the following.

```
2b5e5507-7e01-45fe-b0ed-331135479061,7c816e0f-d6e2-489c-bdce-df064b3e99f9
```

When I use this variable in the WhereIn condition, It shows an error.

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input
> syntax for type uuid:
> "2b5e5507-7e01-45fe-b0ed-331135479061,7c816e0f-d6e2-489c-bdce-df064b3e99f9"

I am using PostgreSQL as a database.

Answer (score 0):

Need's to convert UUID to string

```
$skills = DB::table("industry_skill_sets")
                    ->whereIn('industry_id', explode(',',$id))
                    ->pluck("name","id");
```